# Can anyone please explain how facebook/Gmail android applications send and receive data with server

Tags: android, performance, server-communication

Am new to Android i would like to know how some apps like facebook and Gmail etc., applications perform the background process while hitting the server for request and response to improve the performance of the app.

generally to call a server i use async task onPreExecute() method start progress dialog and in doInBackgraound() method do server call and in postExecute() method dismiss dialog, but this process blocks UI for a while. Where as Some apps(Facebook/Gmail etc.,) doesn't know to user about server communication process.

what is the process apps(Facebook/Gmail etc.,) use for server communication ? Is there any process before and after server communication like maintaining data locally or any other.

My English is not Good Excuse me.

Thanks in advance.